# delimiter inside reqular expression Awk

Tags: regex, awk

I have a term like `aa-and-bb` in the 10th column of a tab limited file, `file.tsv`.

I can get `aa-and-bb` as

```
cat file.tsv | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"};{print $10}'
```

How do I further get `aa` from `aa-and-bb`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use split().

```
split( $10, arr, "-" ); print arr[ 1 ];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee no other `-`s in fields 1-9, you can add `-` as a separator:

```
awk -F'\t|-' '{print $10}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that all three terms, `aa`, `and`, and `bb` are variable, and you want only the first term.

```
cat file.tsv | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"};{print $10}' | sed 's/-.*$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{sub(/-.*$/, "", $10);print $10}' file.tsv
aa
```

But it is not 100% clear how your data looks, so we are just guessing here that you want to split on the dash.